# How should I change this <th> tag to <td> tag Directly by changing a single tag?

Tags: html-table

Here is given the tags and i want to select all the th tag at once by changing just a single td tad so how will it be done

Comment: You can use the JQuery find method to get a list of all objects in the DOM collection that match a certain type, css class, contain a certain property, etc. Is this what you need? 

https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: Could you try to be a little more descriptive on what you need? It's hard to tell if you're trying to do this programmatically,  in an editor like Visual Studio Code, etc.